# Any idea why Gradle Build running takes too long (specifically on crashlytics)?

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

When I hit run it takes up to 5 minutes executing tasks in Gradle. From these 5 minutes, this task: `crashlyticsUploadDeobsDebug`   takes up to 4m 30s. All other tasks take milliseconds.

Any idea on how can I fix this? I have Firebase implemented on my project but it was never an issue, until updating Google Play Services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tested this after offline mode?

Answer (score 2):

You can improve your build speed if you do not want crash reporting for your debug builds, by disabling uploading of your mapping file.

Add this in your module-level `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    // ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }
        }

    }
}
```